# Why can you only specify type restrictions with traits?

Tags: rust, language-design

In Rust you can only use traits to specify type restrictions, for example: `<T: A + B>`, A and B must be traits, they cannot be primitive types like `i32` or `f64`.

```
trait Foo {}

impl Foo for i32 {}

fn blah<T: i32>(val: T) {
    //     ^^^ works if this is Foo
    println!("hello\n");
}

fn main() {
    let toast: i32 = 33;
    blah(toast);
}
```

You can get around this by implementing a trait *for* a primitive, but why would the designers of the language not let you use primitives as a restriction?

Comment: Why not just make it `val: i32` then?

Comment: I'm asking why the language doesn't allow primitive type restrictions for generic parameters. The code example is obviously quite silly, it's to demonstrate a point.

Comment: There's nothing special about a "primitive" (which doesn't really exist in Rust), you also can't say `<T: HashMap>`. The whole point is that a generic allows more than one type. There is already a syntax to specify that a parameter is a specific type: `fn foo(name: SpecificType)`.

Comment: @Shepmaster But I could specify more than one type by doing `T: i32 + f32 + f64` for example, but instead I'd have to make a trait and implement that for each of the primitive types.

Comment: Generic type constraints relate to the contract a type exposes.. not what a type is. That is, they say "This is what the generic type is _allowed to do_" .. not "this is what the generic type _can be_".

Comment: To solve the problem that I expect you are actually having, you probably want to use [one of the traits from the num crate](http://rust-num.github.io/num/num/index.html#traits).

Comment: @Shepmaster It's not a problem I'm having. I just wanted to learn more about why the designers of the language made this particular choice.

Comment: @SimonWhitehead That makes sense! Thank you :)

Comment: *But I could specify more than one type by doing* — doubtful. Choosing just [`i32`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/primitive.i32.html) and [`f64`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/primitive.f64.html), you'll note that there are only a subset of methods in common. What would you want to do for the ones that don't match? What about methods with the **same signature** but which behave differently?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Because specifying type restrictions with types does not make sense.

---

The very reason for using generic programming is to allow *multiple* concrete types. This is why you express *bounds*, and any type that satisfy those bounds can be used.

If you wish to use a concrete type, you certainly can... but not with a generic function; you just use a regular function.

---

Note that bounds are *additives*, that is, when specifying `T: X + Y` you are not saying that any type implementing EITHER X OR Y is expected, but that you want a type that implements BOTH X AND Y. The `+` here is an *intersection*.

As a result:

- `T: i32` is useless, just specify `i32` as the type
- `T: i32 + f32` is non-sensical, no type is BOTH a `i32` and a `f32` at the same type

---

So... how do you specify the OR relationship? By using a trait!

```
trait MyTrait: std::fmt::Display {}

impl MyTrait for i32 {}
impl MyTrait for f32 {}

fn hello<T: MyTrait>(t: &T) {
    println!("{:?}", t);
}
```

*Note: other people may implement your trait for their own types if it is public.*

Comment: Another note: If you (the OP, or a future reader) just need a generic over any numeric type, use the `Num` trait from the `num` crate.